# Confusion regarding calculating shortest path in a cube

Tags: geometry

**An ant is at a corner of a cubical room of side a. The ant can move with constant speed u. The minimum time taken to reach the farthest corner of the cube is**

I am completely clueless how is it possible to determine the shortest path which the insert can as insects can't fly in this case. It has to walk on the cube.
[image]

This is the book's solution

I will be grateful if you help me
Thanks

Comment: Make a cutout of the cube and unfold it so it lies flat along a proposed path. Then shortest distance is seen by drawing a straight line on the unfolded cube with a ruler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The shortest distance between any 2 points is given by the line joining the 2 points.***

If the **ant could fly**, the **shortest distance** would have been given by the body diagonal of the cube, which is $\bf \sqrt3a$.

But ants generally don't fly (thank god!), **ants walk**. So, the shortest distance between 2 points in a cube is hard to see as such. 
But if we **unfold the cube** (as suggested in the comments) then all the points on the cube will now lie on a plane and it's easy to see then that again the shortest path between the 2 points is given by the straight line joining them.

[image: pic]

As you can see in the pic above, that the shortest distance between $PR$ is given by the line joining them, and **using Pythagoras theorem**, we find it's length as follows:
$$PR^2=(2a)^2 + a^2$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed {PR=\sqrt5a}$$

---

Even **if it were a cuboid**, you would have proceeded in a similar manner. Just be careful as there you'll have different combinations as you travel along whether $(lb)$ or $(bh)$ or $(hl)$. Perhaps you'll also **notice** which **combination** would always give the **shortest route**.

Also, note that the **above image** is **not the only way to unfold the cube**, it could be done in any of the following ways (and obviously, they would all give the same answer, use whichever you feel easy to work with):
[image: pic2]

---

I have addressed the main thing, but to get the final answer, you are asked to find the time taken and $\text{Speed}=\text{Distance}/\text{Time}$.
So, time taken, $\bf t$ $=\frac ds=$$\bf\frac {\sqrt5a}u$.